# A large amount of data in many text files - how to process and merge them all?

Tags: python, c++, database, text, data-analysis

I have large amounts of price data(a few gigabytes) and accumulating... They are contained in many text files (each about 60MB) with names such as 220628_Prints. The name stands for YYMMDD. I would like to put all these files in a unique file and add the column with a date. The column info should be taken by the name of the file. Each file has a few million lines so excel isn't a good alternative to use. Maybe a gigantic text file and read it with python? Thanks

Comment: You've tagged this database - have you considered using a database? Since you mentioned the ms Excel spreadsheet, what about ms Access? Its probably easier to get started with than many of the alternative database options.

Comment: csv file would be fine.  there are other formats like pickle.   so long as you dont open the file in an excel sheet to read it, this would be fine.   Alternative is a database.

Comment: Future bug: The naming scheme is vulnerable to the Y2.1k issue.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, but with a bit luck, OP is retired then. (For the same reason, I don't care when the 32 bit Unix clock might wrap around...) ;-)

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly putting it in column, but this should help you get started. If you want you can display it in a column later using a GUI library, just detect the start and end of the file and format accordingly.

This program is ASSUMING THAT FILE NAME FORMAT IS YYMMDD_Prints.txt

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

//Assuming that files are ALL named YYMMDD_Prints


//Place this program in the directory of the input files that you want to transfer to a single file
//Or place all input files that you want to transfer data to an output file where this program is located
//Rename FILE_NAME_HERE to whatever you want the name of the output file to be or it will just be called "FILE_NAME_HERE.txt" if you dont rename it

int main(){
  int yyBegin = 0;           //Set begin year to scan for
  int yyEnd = 23;            //Set end year to scan for
  int mmBegin = 0;
  int mmEnd = 12;
  int ddBegin = 0;
  int ddEnd = 31;
  std::string line;
  std::string fileName = "";
  
  std::fstream wFile;

  //REPLACE THE FILE NAME YOU WANT HERE
  wFile.open("FILE_NAME_HERE.txt", std::ios::app);

  //New file will have XML style format like below
  //<YYMMDD_Prints>
  //DATA INFO
  //</YYMMDD_Prints>
  //So if you want to display the file name in a column, it would be easier to detect when the start and end of a file is.
  for(int yy = yyBegin; yy <= yyEnd; ++yy){
    for(int mm = mmBegin; mm <= mmEnd; ++mm){
      for(int dd = ddBegin; dd <= ddEnd; ++dd){
        std::stringstream fileNameSS;
        if(yy < 10){
          fileNameSS << "0" + std::to_string(yy);
        }else{
          fileNameSS << std::to_string(yy);
        }
        if(mm < 10){
          fileNameSS << "0" + std::to_string(mm);
        }else{
          fileNameSS << std::to_string(mm);
        }
        if(dd < 10){
          fileNameSS << "0" + std::to_string(dd);
        }else{
          fileNameSS << std::to_string(dd);
        }
        fileNameSS << "_Prints.txt";
        fileNameSS >> fileName;
        std::fstream rFile;
        rFile.open(fileName, std::ios::in);
        if(!rFile.is_open()) continue;
        wFile << "<" << fileName << ">" << "\n";
        while(std::getline(rFile, line)){
          wFile << "  " << line << "\n";
        }
        wFile << "</" << fileName << ">" << "\n";
        rFile.close();
      }
    }
  }
  
  std::cout << "Finished!\n";
  wFile.close();
  
  return 0;
}
```

FILE_NAME_HERE.txt output:

```
<010101_Prints.txt>
  file 1 test
  file 1 test
  file 1 test
  file 1 test
  file 1 test
  file 1 test
  file 1 test
  file 1 test
</010101_Prints.txt>
<020202_Prints.txt>
  file 2 test
  file 2 test
  file 2 test
  file 2 test
  file 2 test
  file 2 test
  file 2 test
  file 2 test
  file 2 test
</020202_Prints.txt>
```